# Chess Construction Challenge #2-Check!

Tags: chess, construction

It’s time for round two!

Given that:

- Black has 6 pawns and a king
- White has three pieces of any kind you to deduce the identity of and a king

Construct:

- A legal position in which both sides help to give a legal sequence of 13 mutual checks

Position variations are allowed. To my knowledge, there is really only one way in which this idea can be constructed. I accept alternate answers.

If you have questions, feel free to ask in the comments section below!

Good luck!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My position has a fourteenth check too, but that's probably ok. :-)

> [image]
>  `[FEN "8/8/8/8/8/4K3/2pppppp/RR4Nk w - -"]`

These are the moves:

> ```
>  1. Nh3+  d1=N+
>  2. Rxd1+ cxd1=N+
>  3. Rxd1+ e1=R+
>  4. Rxe1+ f1=N+
>  5. Rxf1+ g1=B+
>  6. Rxg1+ hxg1=B+
>  7. Nf2+  Bxf2+
> ```

And here's [the whole solution](https://lichess.org/Z9Als8vy) uploaded to Lichess.

---

EDIT: Looks like 15 is also doable:

> [image]

The final check feels like such a waste of a piece though; the first fourteen checks are possible with white having only two pieces and a king:

> [FEN "8/8/6Q1/8/5R2/5p2/ppp1p1p1/R3K1k1 w - -"]
>
> ```
>  1. Qb6+   f2+
>  2. Kd2+   b1=N+
>  3. Qxb1+  axb1=N+
>  4. Rxb1+  c1=B+
>  5. Rxc1+  e1=B+
>  6. Rxe1+  f1=N+
>  7. Rexf1+ gxf1=N+
>  8. Rxf1+
> ```

Again, here's the [Lichess link](https://lichess.org/NcHxslKc).

Comment: Incredible!  Thank goodness I checked back.  I was wasting so much time not considering promotions! Would love to know your thought process?  Had you just seen this kind of pattern before?

Comment: nice.  I think you could substitute queens for one or both of the rooks, too.

Comment: Well, there seemed to be very few options for b to give check, so it seemed obvious that at least some of black's checks had to be promotions. -> maybe they could all be? I then managed to find a couple of ways to do just that, and one of them had an extra check at the end.

Comment: Nice job on finding one more than I thought was possible @Bass! Here's my setup for 13 mutual checks. I'm sure that you can figure out the moves! ;D: 7Q/8/8/8/8/1R3R2/pppKppp1/k7 w - - 0 1

Comment: @RewanDemontay TWO more :-)